# Tensor structure in Image processing

Tags: image, matlab

My question is with regards to the question in this link   [What is the significance of the eigenvalues of an autocorrelation matrix in image processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344930/what-is-the-significance-of-the-eigenvalues-of-an-autocorrelation-matrix-in-imag/24353360#24353360)

As I understand, tensor structure is a matrix with square of gradients of the image as its elements.
The equation is also available in that link.

I had a doubt regarding the squaring of the gradient matrix.

**Question I:** When I take the gradient derivatives of an image, the resultant is again a matrix with the dimensions of the image. Now when I square the matrices to get the square of the derivatives as shown in the formula above, I am a bit confused then. How do we do it ? (I am using Matlab notations since I am more comfortable with them)

**1)** Ix_squared = Ix*transpose(Ix); %The resultant is a square matrix

**or

2)** 
Ix_squared = Ix.* Ix;  %The resultant is a matrix of dimensions of Ix
(where the pixel value at each indices is multiplied by itself)

**Question II:** Again, wiki explains that the Tensor structure A is a symmetric square matrix. That means, Ix and Iy also have to be square matrices to achieve A as a symmetric square matrix. Coming back to Images, does that mean I can only find out the structure tensor of a square images ? and not non square matrices ? Or should I divide my rectangular image into square patches and store the tensor structure of the patches as an array?

Comment: Hi there.  I am the author of the answer to the post you are referring to.  To answer your questions (actually they've already been answered in the answer below): Question #1 - You should do `Ix.*Ix`.  Question #2 - No, the structure tensor can be defined **for any size matrix you want**.  You compute all of the values required for the structure tensor matrix, **then create a 2 x 2 matrix** of those values for each patch you calculate in the image.  Within a particular patch, you add up all of the Ix^2, Iy^2 and the Ixy terms together within the patch.

Answer (score 2):

In the same way that computing the image gradient does not require your image to be a vector, computing the structure tensor of an image does not require your image to be a square matrix.

You are mixing the values of the structure tensor (a square, symmetric matrix indeed) and its domain of definition, which happen to be a rectangular image represented by a matrix in Matlab. Both are unrelated. The image could be defined on a circular domain and you could still compute a structure tensor, and the values would still be matrices, albeit on a circular domain.

Actually, in 2D, the structure tensor is a 2x2 matrix. Much smaller than your image. But, as for the gradient, it is a value defined for each pixel. So, when you compute

```
 Ix_squared = Ix.* Ix
```

you only get the first of the four coefficient of the structure tensor matrix. In the same way that `Ix` itself is (presumably, based on your notation) only one component of the gradient.

Comment: My notations: Ix, Iy = gradient in x,y direction of image I of [MxN] dimensions. Now, Tensor structure A is a 2x2 matrix consisting of A11 = Ix_squared, A12 = A21 = Ixy & A22 = Iy_squared.
So, are you saying that there are M*N number of 2x2 structure tensors for a MxN image ?

Comment: +1 - Good job in the further explanation!  Yes, for each location or for certain locations in your image, you would surround a region over this pixel, collect all of the Ix^2, Iy^2 and Ixy terms, and sum them up.  Each of these terms will then go into a 2 x 2 matrix, denoted as `A`.